# Namespace collision of ISet: System.Collections.Generic and Iesi.Collections.Generic

Tags: c#, .net

When upgrading project from 3.5 to 4.0 I encountered the collision of ISet class that exists in both
namespace:

```
System.Collections.Generic 
Iesi.Collections.Generic
```

I have those two classes in hundreds of files. Prior to 4.0 there was not ISet in System.Collections.Generic.

How would you solve this pain ... ? Should I really add to each file: Iesi.Collections.Generic to ISet?

or give an alias:

```
using IesiGeneric = Iesi.Collections.Generic;
```

and use like that: IesiGeneric.ISet but all these means I have to change all those files ....

Is there another option?

UPDATE

What about creating interface like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Iesi.Collections.Generic;

namespace NameSpace
{
  public interface IesiSet<T> : ISet<T>
  {
  }
}
```

and change Iesi Iset's to: IesiSet?

Comment: You can try to declare a `global` namespace alias using [`::`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/namespace-alias-qualifier) operator

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add an alias directly to the type:

```
using ISet = Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet;
```

Which should mean you ONLY need to update the head of each file.

However, going forward, I expect overtime (particularly as personnel changes) this is going to become a maintainability gotcha as people assume this is the built in ISet.  I would take the pain now and replace globally now.

[also

> I encountered the collision of ISet class that exists in both namespace

System.Collections.Generic.ISet is an *interface*.  If your version is a *class* I would consider taking the pain of renaming it now, as it looks like an interface name]

Comment: What do you think about my edited question to create another interface and use it ... ?

Comment: By the way adding your way that namespace gives compiler error ...